# style of card like POST card in facbook

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

hope you all rightI want to create a social media website and I need to create a postcard to display text and image, I don't know how to display multiple images in one card like Facebook (I am using react js) thanks in advance.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlwDL.png)

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I am just create a card that contains text and one image